# How to get Aggregated Results in Loopback querying Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

I am new to loopback and need a fix for the following problem. I need distinct results from mongo of two fields(email and name both).

Data :

> var a = [  { email: 'x@gmail.com',name: 'x'}, { email:
>   'x@gmail.com',name: 'x'}, { email: 'x@gmail.com',name: 'z'} ]

Output :

```
var a = [ 
{ email: 'x@gmail.com',name: 'x'},
{ email: 'x@gmail.com',name: 'z'}
]
```

How could I use the following aggregate function in loopback to get desired Output results.

```
collection = db.tb;
result = collection.aggregate( 
            [
                {"$group": { "_id": { email: "$email", name: "$name" } } }
            ]
        );
```

(Source [How to efficiently perform "distinct" with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys) )

Answer (score 3):

Use an additional `$group` and a `$project` stage to project the desired output,

- `Group` by `email` and `name`, to get a single record for each unique
  combination.
- Again `group` together all the records and accumulate the `_id`
  obtained in the previous stage using the `$push` operator.
- `Project` the `records` field and exclude the `_id` field.

Code:

```
 result = collection.aggregate( 
        [
            {$group:{"_id":{"email": "$email","name": "$name" }}},
            {$group:{"_id":null,"records":{$push:"$_id"}}},
            {$project:{"_id":0,"records":1}},
        ]
    );
```

o/p:

```
{
        "records" : [
                {
                        "email" : "x@gmail.com",
                        "name" : "z"
                },
                {
                        "email" : "x@gmail.com",
                        "name" : "x"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: "how could I use the following code...." So is this "loopback code" you posted here. It doesn't look like it. I think most people in the community would prefer the "experts" who answer their questions to actually be an "expert" of some knowledge in the question they asked.

Comment: Exactly Neil.I need Loopback code to implement this.

Comment: @Vaibhav- I just wanted to give the idea of how its to be done. Just thought this could be used by the post owner to understand how it needs to be done. You could always leave this answer as unaccepted and can wait for an expert to answer it or try transforming the syntax for `loopback`. I could suggest you a starting point - http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/MongoDB+connector#MongoDBconnector-Querywithlogicaloperators(sincev1.2.3), https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/890.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is a little late, but I'm hoping it may be of value to someone else stumbling upon this. To access mongo aggregate functionality in loopback you must bypass abstraction, as a result your code is no longer database agnostic, bear this in mind as if you ever switch databases you will have to alter this code. In loopback you would write the following code:

```
var connector = app.dataSources.yourMongoConnector.connector

result = connector.collection("yourCollection").aggregate([
            {"$group": { "_id": { email: "$email", name: "$name" } } }
        ])
```

You could use this method to access any of the database operations not present in loopback. I have not tested the aggregate method yet, but have successfully used this with findAndModify() and distinct() - so there is no doubt it will work with aggregate or anything else in the mongoDb documentation.

Comment: Only problem here, is that the result will be an "Object" and not the persisted object you are looking for