# mongodb aggregating object keys to find distinct values

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with document structure as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551d41bc0474fa4b03e4c072"),
    "last_fetch_date" : ISODate("2015-04-02T18:48:52.573Z"),
    "specifications" : {
        "pattern" : "Striped",
        "fit" : "Slim",
        "fabric" : "Cotton Linen",
        "ideal_for" : "Men's",
        "sleeve" : "Full Sleeve"
    }
}
```

I need to aggregate the data to find distinct values of lets say pattern, fit and fabric across all the documents in the collection. Currently I am writing separate queries for each attribute. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {
        "$group": { "_id": "fabric", "values": {"$addToSet": "$specifications.fabric"} }
    }
)
```

To explain more clearly, I want my output to be something like this (aggregated across all the documents )

```
{
    "fabric": ["cotton", "satin", "linen"],
    "fit": ["slim", "regular"],
    "pattern": ["stipes", "checkered", "floral", "solid"]
}
```

Is there any way to compute this in one go and that too efficiently (performance is important) ?

Comment: Do you need the distinct values for each of the fields or the distinct values for the existing combinations of those fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to efficiently perform "distinct" with multiple keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys)

Comment: I need distinct values for each of the fields. But I know in advance what all fields exists in my collection. Some fields might exist in one doc but not in other docs so its not the same fields in every doc

Comment: @yogesh : this question is quite different from the one you posted link for. That one is quite trivial