# Mongodb aggregation in mongo command prompt

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following code based upon this question 
[How to efficiently perform "distinct" with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys):

```
collection = db.products;
result = collection.aggregate( 
            [
                {"$group": { "_id": { "P1 Connection": "$p1c", "P1 Size": "$p1s" } } },
                {"$match" : {"parentGUID":ObjectId("5509b246c519ce4b900138a3")}}
            ]
        )
printjson(result);
```

The printjson statement only prints a bunch of code, and not an object.  I also tried result() but that got the following error:

```
> result()
2015-10-29T10:31:14.892-0400 TypeError: Property 'result' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

How do I get the results of this aggregation?  It looks like it may be possible to do this if I put my code in a file and run that, but I am having a hard time believing that there is no quick and dirty way to run this query in the mongodb command prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)** pipeline step to the very beginning, this will filter the documents that get into the pipeline and the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline stage will then run the pipeline with the correct documents. Since MongoDB 2.6 adds support for returning a cursor for the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)** method, you would need to iterate over the cursor using the **[`forEach()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/#cursor.forEach)** method and access the documents, as in the following example:

```
var pipeline = [
    {"$match" : {"parentGUID":ObjectId("5509b246c519ce4b900138a3")}},
    {"$group": { "_id": { "P1 Connection": "$p1c", "P1 Size": "$p1s" } } }                
];
var results =  db.products.aggregate( pipeline );

results.forEach(printjson);
```

Comment: This produces results much more like what I would expect.