# Mongodb finding distinct values using multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to show distinct values of two fields. Not sure it is possible to return values from the two fields in my `Mongodb`.

I have tried this:

```
db.sInsert.distinct("post_id","post_message").
```

But it is not possible to do so.

Comment: what do you mean by distinct value on two fields? Is post_id also stored in post_message? Or do you want distinct on combination of post_id and post_message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently perform "distinct" with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $group in aggregation

```
db.sInsert.aggregate( [ {"$group": { "_id": { post_id: "$post_id", post_message: "$post_message" } } } ]);
```