# How to get distinct combinations of two fields from a collection when one of the fields is in an array of subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, tuples, aggregation-framework, distinct-values

From a collection consisting of documents representing products similar to the following:

```
[
  {
    code: "0WE3A5CMY",
    name: "lorem",
    category: "voluptas",
    variants: [
      {
        color: "PapayaWhip",
        stock: 17,
        barcode: 4937310396997
      },
      {
        color: "RoyalBlue",
        stock: 13,
        barcode: 9787252504890
      },
      {
        color: "DodgerBlue",
        stock: 110,
        barcode: 97194456959791
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    code: "0WE3A5CMX",
    name: "ipsum",
    category: "temporibus",
    variants: [
      {
        color: "RoyalBlue",
        stock: 113,
        barcode: 23425202111840
      },
      {
        color: "DodgerBlue",
        stock: 10,
        barcode: 2342520211841
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    code: "0WE3A5CMZ",
    name: "dolor",
    category: "temporibus",
    variants: [
      {
        color: "MaroonRed",
        stock: 17,
        barcode: 3376911253701
      },
      {
        color: "RoyalBlue",
        stock: 12,
        barcode: 3376911253702
      },
      {
        color: "DodgerBlue",
        stock: 4,
        barcode: 3376911253703
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to retrieve distinct combinations of `variants.color` and `category`. So the result should be:

```
[
    {
        category: 'voluptas',
        color: 'PapayaWhip',
    },
    {
        category: 'voluptas',
        color: 'RoyalBlue',
    },
    {
        category: 'voluptas',
        color: 'DodgerBlue',
    },
    {
        category: 'temporibus',
        color: 'RoyalBlue',
    },
    {
        category: 'temporibus',
        color: 'DodgerBlue',
    }
]
```

Based on some cursory research I think I will have to use an aggregate but I've never worked with those and could use some help. I've tried the solution at [How to efficiently perform "distinct" with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys) 
I've tried the method mentioned by jcarter in the comments but it doesn't solve my problem. If I do:

```js
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "category": "$category",
        "color": "$variants.color"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

I get the result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "category": "temporibus",
      "color": [
        "MaroonRed",
        "RoyalBlue",
        "DodgerBlue"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "category": "temporibus",
      "color": [
        "RoyalBlue",
        "DodgerBlue"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "category": "voluptas",
      "color": [
        "PapayaWhip",
        "RoyalBlue",
        "DodgerBlue"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Which isn't what I need.

Comment: Hi, Kaan! I believe this is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys

Comment: Isn't `category` unique across all docs also `color` unique across all `variants` for a category ?

Comment: @whoami Well I haven't provided a full dataset for the sake of brevity. So there would definately be more than one document with the same category.

Comment: @jcarter I've tried that solution but it provides wierd results. I will update the question

Comment: jcarter/kaan : Yes `$group` stage is used to group on individual docs & return groups of docs combined together based on criteria ( here based on two fields `category + variants`). But actual issue is `color` is in an array `variants` so in group stage when you do `"color": "$variants.color"` it would get all `'variants.color'`/`colors` from all elements of `variants` array of a doc into an array. So we need to first `$unwind` variants to get strings for `colors` rather than arrays..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `variants` is an array you need to unwind it & group on two fields to get unique docs based on `category + 'variants.color'` combo.

As group stage results something like :

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "category": "voluptas",
      "color": "DodgerBlue"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "category": "voluptas",
      "color": "PapayaWhip"
    }
  }
]
```

then using `$replaceRoot` stage you can make `_id` object field as root for each document to get desired result.

**Query :**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
      $unwind: "$variants"
    },
    {
      $group: { _id: { "category": "$category", "color": "$variants.color" } }
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$_id" }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Krm_W7k_JYu)